# Some of the javascript functions on my web page work while other don't. What do I do/

Tags: javascript, html, css, error-handling

I created a calculator using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

But while the buttons for the numbers 1 to 9 plus the operators +, -, *, / and % work perfectly, the number 0, C and = don't work.

The code for the buttons that don't work is quite similar to the ones that do work so I;m not sure what the problem is.

Below is the code:

```js
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "1";
});
document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "2";
});
document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "3";
});
document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "4";
});
document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "5";
});
document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "6";
});
document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "7";
});
document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "8";
});
document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "9";
});
document.getElementById("period").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += ".";
});
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "+";
});
document.getElementById("subtract").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "-";
});
document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "*";
});
document.getElementById("divide").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "/";
});
document.getElementById("percentage").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "*(1/100)";
});

//clear calculation
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value = "0";
});

// get result
document.getElementById("getResult").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("result").value = eval(document.getElementById("calculation").value);
});
```

```css
:root {
    --main-color: darkblue;
    --secondary-color: blue;
    --tertiary-color: #318ce7;
    --dark-color: #444;
    --light-color: #fafafa;
}
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: var(--dark-color);
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.calculator {
    
    box-shadow: var(--main-color) 1px 1px 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 370px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-135deg,var(--secondary-color),var(--tertiary-color),var(--secondary-color));
    overflow: hidden;
}
.output {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--tertiary-color);
    padding: 2em 0px;
}
.result,.calculation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: end;
}
#result,#calculation {
    padding: 0.3em 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--light-color);
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: inherit;
}
::placeholder {
  color: var(--light-color);
}
#result {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.result {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.calculation {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.keyboard {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
}
button {
    margin: 0.2em 0.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 50%;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
button:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--secondary-color),var(--tertiary-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--light-color);
    box-shadow: var(--main-color) 1px 1px 1em;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
button:active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--light-color);
    opacity: 100%;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calculator">
      <section class="output">
        <section class="result">
          <input id="result" placeholder="0" disabled />
        </section>
        <section class="calculation">
          <input id="calculation" disabled placeholder="0" />
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="keyboard">
        <button id="clear">C</button>
        <button id="brackets">( )</button>
        <button id="percentage">%</button>
        <button id="divide">/</button>
        <button id="seven">7</button>
        <button id="eight">8</button>
        <button id="nine">9</button>
        <button id="multiply">X</button>
        <button id="four">4</button>
        <button id="five">5</button>
        <button id="six">6</button>
        <button>-</button>
        <button id="one" class="getResult2">1</button>
        <button id="two">2</button>
        <button id="three">3</button>
        <button id="add">+</button>
        <button id="change-sign">+/-</button>
        <button id="zero">0</button>
        <button id="period">.</button>
        <button id="getResult">=</button>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me figure out what the problem is?

Also, I wanted to write a rule where the input of id "result" will automatically update itself whenever there is a change to the input with id "calculation" but it did not work.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Add a [mcve] that doesn't throw an error that is not part of the question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your subtract button's `id` attribute to `"subtract"` and add an event listener to the element with the id `zero`:

```js
document.getElementById("zero").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "0";
});
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "1";
});
document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "2";
});
document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "3";
});
document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "4";
});
document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "5";
});
document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "6";
});
document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "7";
});
document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "8";
});
document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "9";
});
document.getElementById("period").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += ".";
});
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "+";
});
document.getElementById("subtract").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "-";
});
document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "*";
});
document.getElementById("divide").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "/";
});
document.getElementById("percentage").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "*(1/100)";
});

//clear calculation
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value = "0";
});

// get result
document.getElementById("getResult").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("result").value = eval(document.getElementById("calculation").value);
});
```

```css
:root {
    --main-color: darkblue;
    --secondary-color: blue;
    --tertiary-color: #318ce7;
    --dark-color: #444;
    --light-color: #fafafa;
}
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: var(--dark-color);
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.calculator {
    
    box-shadow: var(--main-color) 1px 1px 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 370px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-135deg,var(--secondary-color),var(--tertiary-color),var(--secondary-color));
    overflow: hidden;
}
.output {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--tertiary-color);
    padding: 2em 0px;
}
.result,.calculation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: end;
}
#result,#calculation {
    padding: 0.3em 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--light-color);
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: inherit;
}
::placeholder {
  color: var(--light-color);
}
#result {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.result {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.calculation {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.keyboard {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
}
button {
    margin: 0.2em 0.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 50%;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
button:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--secondary-color),var(--tertiary-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--light-color);
    box-shadow: var(--main-color) 1px 1px 1em;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
button:active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--light-color);
    opacity: 100%;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calculator">
      <section class="output">
        <section class="result">
          <input id="result" placeholder="0" disabled />
        </section>
        <section class="calculation">
          <input id="calculation" disabled placeholder="0" />
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="keyboard">
        <button id="clear">C</button>
        <button id="brackets">( )</button>
        <button id="percentage">%</button>
        <button id="divide">/</button>
        <button id="seven">7</button>
        <button id="eight">8</button>
        <button id="nine">9</button>
        <button id="multiply">X</button>
        <button id="four">4</button>
        <button id="five">5</button>
        <button id="six">6</button>
        <button id="subtract">-</button>
        <button id="one" class="getResult2">1</button>
        <button id="two">2</button>
        <button id="three">3</button>
        <button id="add">+</button>
        <button id="change-sign">+/-</button>
        <button id="zero">0</button>
        <button id="period">.</button>
        <button id="getResult">=</button>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were running into 2 different issues. First off, there was never an event listener set for the id `zero`. Second, there was not an id set for the subtract button, so the script failed at that `getElementById` and the remaining script. The below works well:

```js
document.getElementById("zero").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "0";
});
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "1";
});
document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "2";
});
document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "3";
});
document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "4";
});
document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "5";
});
document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "6";
});
document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "7";
});
document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "8";
});
document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "9";
});
document.getElementById("period").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += ".";
});
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "+";
});
document.getElementById("subtract").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "-";
});
document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "*";
});
document.getElementById("divide").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "/";
});
document.getElementById("percentage").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value += "*(1/100)";
});

//clear calculation
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("calculation").value = "0";
});

// get result
document.getElementById("getResult").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("result").value = eval(document.getElementById("calculation").value);
});
```

```css
:root {
    --main-color: darkblue;
    --secondary-color: blue;
    --tertiary-color: #318ce7;
    --dark-color: #444;
    --light-color: #fafafa;
}
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: var(--dark-color);
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.calculator {
    
    box-shadow: var(--main-color) 1px 1px 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 370px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-135deg,var(--secondary-color),var(--tertiary-color),var(--secondary-color));
    overflow: hidden;
}
.output {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--tertiary-color);
    padding: 2em 0px;
}
.result,.calculation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: end;
}
#result,#calculation {
    padding: 0.3em 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--light-color);
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: inherit;
}
::placeholder {
  color: var(--light-color);
}
#result {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.result {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.calculation {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.keyboard {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
}
button {
    margin: 0.2em 0.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 50%;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
button:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--secondary-color),var(--tertiary-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--light-color);
    box-shadow: var(--main-color) 1px 1px 1em;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
button:active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color));
    color: var(--light-color);
    opacity: 100%;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calculator">
      <section class="output">
        <section class="result">
          <input id="result" placeholder="0" disabled />
        </section>
        <section class="calculation">
          <input id="calculation" disabled placeholder="0" />
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="keyboard">
        <button id="clear">C</button>
        <button id="brackets">( )</button>
        <button id="percentage">%</button>
        <button id="divide">/</button>
        <button id="seven">7</button>
        <button id="eight">8</button>
        <button id="nine">9</button>
        <button id="multiply">X</button>
        <button id="four">4</button>
        <button id="five">5</button>
        <button id="six">6</button>
        <button id="subtract">-</button>
        <button id="one" class="getResult2">1</button>
        <button id="two">2</button>
        <button id="three">3</button>
        <button id="add">+</button>
        <button id="change-sign">+/-</button>
        <button id="zero">0</button>
        <button id="period">.</button>
        <button id="getResult">=</button>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```